# R function returns error, performing steps in console yields correct answer

Tags: r

I have an R function that takes three arguments, creates a dataframe from the files in the directory I specify, then returns the mean of a column I name. The code looks something like this:

```
 meanOfAColumn(directory, columnName, numberOfFilesInDirectory){
    df = data.frame()
    filesList <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    for (i in numberOfFilesInDirectory) {
        df <- rbind(df, read.csv(filesList[i], header = TRUE
    }
    mean(df$columnName, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

I know this is a crummy way to get all of the files into the dataframe; looping in R is slooooow. However, I'm prepared to deal with that if the function returns the right answer. It doesn't. I get 
`[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df$columnName, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA` instead of the correct answer.

Which, fine, but when I literally copy-paste the lines from my function into the R console in R-Studio and run them that way, I get the correct answer. I am using the source() command, so I don't think it's that the function isn't updated.

Comment: (1) `df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(filesList,read.csv,header=TRUE))`  should work better for the first 5 lines of your function; (2) are you sure you don't mean `df[[columnName]]` ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker (2) worked, but I'm not sure why--both df$columnName and df[[columnName]] return the same thing from my console. What's wrong with df$columnName that causes the function to barf but the console to accept it? Also if you want to type that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Debugging 101: how does your df look like before you compute the mean?  In particular, what is in the `columnName`?  The error message suggests you have some non-numbers that are not NA-s.  For instance, some of your numbers may have been converted to factors.

Comment: You need `for (i in 1:numberOfFilesInDirectory)`, or you're only running your loop once. And add some closing parentheses. And `function`. Ultimately it's probably a type/factor error as @OttToomet said (add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv()`; check out `str()` on the data you're trying to `rbind`), but cleaner code will show what's going on. Sample data will improve the likelihood of getting a useful answer, too.